# There is an error code whenever I try to do the following codes for UE4 FPS Tutorial Section 2.7. What am I missing?

Tags: c++, error-handling, compiler-errors, camera, unreal-engine4

FPSCharacter.h
This is the first code needed for the tutorial. Essentially, I was told to add a camera component to this.

// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Character.h"
#include "FPSCharacter.generated.h"
#include "Camera/CameraComponent.h"

UCLASS()
class FPSPROJECT_API AFPSCharacter : public ACharacter
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    // Sets default values for this character's properties
    AFPSCharacter();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public:
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick( float DeltaSeconds ) override;

    // Called to bind functionality to input
    virtual void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent) override;

    // Handles input for moving forward and backward.
    UFUNCTION()
    void MoveForward(float Value);

    // Handles input for moving right and left.
    UFUNCTION()
    void MoveRight(float Value);

    // Sets jump flag when key is pressed.
    UFUNCTION()
    void StartJump();

    // Clears jump flag when key is released.
    UFUNCTION()
    void StopJump();

    // FPS camera.
    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere)
    UCameraComponent* FPSCameraComponent;
};

FPSCharacter.cpp
```

This is the second code provided by the tutorial. Essentially, the goal was to create a UCameraComponent by adding it to the constructor.

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "FPSProject.h"
#include "FPSCharacter.h"
#include "Camera/CameraComponent.h"

// Sets default values
AFPSCharacter::AFPSCharacter()
{
    // Set this character to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    // Create a first person camera component.
    FPSCameraComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UCameraComponent>(TEXT("FirstPersonCamera"));
    // Attach the camera component to our capsule component.
    FPSCameraComponent->SetupAttachment(GetCapsuleComponent());
    // Position the camera slightly above the eyes.
    FPSCameraComponent->SetRelativeLocation(FVector(0.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f + BaseEyeHeight));
    // Allow the pawn to control camera rotation.
    FPSCameraComponent->bUsePawnControlRotation = true;
}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void AFPSCharacter::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    if (GEngine)
    {
        // Put up a debug message for five seconds. The -1 "Key" value (first argument) indicates that we will never need to update or refresh this message.
        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.0f, FColor::Red, TEXT("We are using FPSCharacter."));
    }
}

// Called every frame
void AFPSCharacter::Tick( float DeltaTime )
{
    Super::Tick( DeltaTime );

}

// Called to bind functionality to input
void AFPSCharacter::SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
    Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(PlayerInputComponent);

    // Set up "movement" bindings.
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("MoveForward", this, &AFPSCharacter::MoveForward);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("MoveRight", this, &AFPSCharacter::MoveRight);

    // Set up "look" bindings.
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("Turn", this, &AFPSCharacter::AddControllerYawInput);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("LookUp", this, &AFPSCharacter::AddControllerPitchInput);

    // Set up "action" bindings.
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("Jump", IE_Pressed, this, &AFPSCharacter::StartJump);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("Jump", IE_Released, this, &AFPSCharacter::StopJump);
}

void AFPSCharacter::MoveForward(float Value)
{
    // Find out which way is "forward" and record that the player wants to move that way.
    FVector Direction = FRotationMatrix(Controller->GetControlRotation()).GetScaledAxis(EAxis::X);
    AddMovementInput(Direction, Value);
}

void AFPSCharacter::MoveRight(float Value)
{
    // Find out which way is "right" and record that the player wants to move that way.
    FVector Direction = FRotationMatrix(Controller->GetControlRotation()).GetScaledAxis(EAxis::Y);
    AddMovementInput(Direction, Value);
}

void AFPSCharacter::StartJump()
{
    bPressedJump = true;
}

void AFPSCharacter::StopJump()
{
    bPressedJump = false;
}
The errors I get for both codes are as follows Error: Command/Users/apple/UE_4.25/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Mac/XcodeBuild.sh failed with exit code 6

These two codes are needed in order to create a new camera for the pawn. I can't go to the next step unless I'm able to get this done. This would be greatly appreciated as I have been trying to get this done for hours now to no avail.
```

Comment: Whenever the error is effectively useless it usually means the ubt has error'd as opposed to C++. Try looking at the output window for a more useful error. I won't attempt to eyeball every error but a couple of obvious ones are : not making `FPSCharacter.generated.h` the last include in your header and not making `FPSCharacter.h` the first include in your your cpp. Also not an error but I think including `CoreMinimal.h` in your cpp is a bit overly verbose.

Comment: Turns out the problem was I needed to add a class to the UCameraComponent line at the end of FPSCharacter.h. I wish Unreal Engine would update their tutorials they're vastly outdated